# Ember Data Not Using Irregular Route For Find But Is For CreateRecord

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-data, inflector

I was wondering would someone be able to help. I am using an irregular route name which seems to be working when calling the createRecord on the store but not on the find.

In the router.js file, I am specifying the route paths as follows:

```
this.route('admin', function() {
    this.route('staff');
});

// This is so the parent route data does not display in the sub-route
this.route('admin.staff.create-staff', { path: '/admin/staff/create-staff' });
```

Then in the inflector model file, I am specifying the following irregularities:

```
inflector.irregular('create-staff', 'staff');
```

Now in the route, within the model function, I am specifying the following:

```
model(params) {
    var model = null;

    const id = params.id;
    if(id) {
        model = this.store.find('create-staff', id);            
    } else {
        model = this.store.createRecord('create-staff'); 
    }

    return model;
},
```

Everything is working when I call the model without any query parameters (i.e. it's calling a GET request to REST API endpoint at ...../staff/). But when I do specify the query parameters, it's not working correctly and not going to the irregular path as specified above (i.e. it's calling a GET request to the REST API at ......./createStaff/{id}).

Would anyone be able to help me with making sure that the 'find' and 'createRecord' are both directed to the irregular 'staff' endpoint on the REST API?

Thanks in advance
Graham

Comment: Where is the `inflector.irregular` code?

Comment: Hi @locks, So I seem to be having a problem when I'm working on sub levels. When I create adapter as 'ember g adapter admin/staff/create-staff', model as '.. admin/staff/create-staff', route as '.. admin/staff/create-staff' and template as '.. admin/staff/create-staff', this is when I can't get it to work. I've tried this with the inflector as 'Inflector.inflector.irregular('admin/staff/create-staff', 'staff'') but it still won't aim for ....../staff. Would you have any direction at all on what's the best way to approach or resolve the problems I'm having????

Comment: @locks, the inflector code is in an initialize file. I previously had it in a model file.